# Efficient using of row_number over multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to implement efficient user ratings in SQL Server 2008 R2 where records are constantly changing and each write of user data leads to subsequent read of rating which is just a `ROW_NUMBER` over multiple columns.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Scores]
(
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [UserId] int NOT NULL,
    [MaxLevel] int NOT NULL,
    [BestDiff] int NOT NULL,
    [BestDiffGames] int NOT NULL,
    [BestDiffLastDate] datetime NOT NULL,
    [MaxLevelLastWinDate] datetime,

    -- other statistics

CONSTRAINT [PK_Scores] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Scores_REF_Users] FOREIGN KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id])
)
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Scores_User ON dbo.Scores
(
    UserId
)
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Scores_Rating ON dbo.Scores
(
    MaxLevel desc, BestDiff desc, BestDiffGames desc, 
    BestDiffLastDate desc, MaxLevelLastWinDate desc
)
GO
```

Each write to `Scores` table leads to subsequent read like this:

```
with Ratings (Rating, UserId) as
(
    select (ROW_NUMBER() over 
        (order by MaxLevel desc, BestDiff desc, BestDiffGames desc, 
    BestDiffLastDate desc, MaxLevelLastWinDate desc)) as Rating, 
        UserId
    from Scores with (nolock)
) 
select @Rating = Rating
from Ratings 
where UserId = @UserId
```

Also there are queries for rating pages using the same `ROW_NUMBER`.
Currently the table `Scores` contains about 30K rows and when I run the latter query, execution plan looks nice but it has execution duration about 100-200ms! It is unacceptable for several user rating updates per second during peak workloads.

I wonder if there are more efficient ways to organize user ratings?

**UPDATE 1:** Thanks to **Gordon Linoff** I made further experiments and the final optimized way to get user rating is to use the query above and the following modified index (**non-unique!**):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Scores_Rating ON dbo.Scores
(
    MaxLevel desc, BestDiff desc, BestDiffGames desc, 
    BestDiffLastDate desc, MaxLevelLastWinDate desc,
    UserId
)
GO
```

**UPDATE 2:** Thanks to **Mikael Eriksson** the following query with `top 1` boosted the query speed by **2x** even for middle rated users! Top rated users gained up to **8x** faster query. These speed improvement numbers were achieved *after* optimization 1 (index change), so the current execution time dropped to 2-16ms since the initial 100-200ms that is 6-100 times faster than initially!

```
with Ratings (Rating, UserId) as
(
    select (ROW_NUMBER() over 
        (order by MaxLevel desc, BestDiff desc, BestDiffGames desc, 
    BestDiffLastDate desc, MaxLevelLastWinDate desc)) as Rating, 
        UserId
    from Scores with (nolock)
) 
select top 1 @Rating = Rating
from Ratings 
where UserId = @UserId
```

Comment: What rating is returned when you have multiple rows with the same UserId? To me it looks like it can be just about any rating value for the specified user. You should probably add a min() or max() in the main query.

Comment: Or perhaps a unique constraint on UserId?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, I'm sorry that it was not mentioned: yes, there is an unique index on UserId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100-200 ms doesn't seem that bad.

If you had just one column for the ratings, then you might be able to do:

```
select @Rating = 1 + count(*)
from scores s cross join
     (select * from scores s where userId = @UserId) su
where s.score > su.score;
```

This isn't *exactly* the same if you have ties; it is equivalent to a `rank()` rather than a `row_number()`, so it handles ties differently.  If you could get the columns into a single column with an index, this should be fast.

You can do the same thing with multiple columns, but the logic gets complicated, and I'm not 100% sure the index will always get used properly.  Something like:

```
where s.score > su.score or
      (s.score = su.score and s.bestdiff > su.bestdif) or
      (s.score = su.score and s.bestdiff =  su.bestdif and s.BestDiffGames > su.BestDiffGames) or
      (s.score = su.score and s.bestdiff =  su.bestdif and s.BestDiffGames = su.BestDiffGames and s.MaxLevelLastWinDate > su.MaxLevelLastWinDate)
```

Comment: I marked this answer as correct because with provided indexes your approach with multiple `OR` statements was *5-10 times faster* than with `ROW_NUMBER`. However, when I appended column `UserId` to the end of `IX_Scores_Rating` the speed flipped to the opposite: query with `ROW_NUMBER` was 1.4 times faster than with `OR` statements while performance of the latter was not affected by index change.

Comment: I used Client Statistics in SQL Management Studio to measure query times on DB server. The reason why query with `ROW_NUMBER` after index tuning was faster than query with `OR` statements is most likely in the number of SELECT statements which DB engine had to perform: Client Stats reported 1 versus 3 SELECT statements for both queries.

Comment: @IPSUS you could also try to add `top(1)` to the row_number version. It could make a difference for the users with the lower ranks. SQL server will stop enumerating when one row is found and since UserId is unique it will make no difference in the result.

Comment: @Mikael, this is impressive - `top 1` boosted query speed by **2x** even for middle rated users! Top rated users gained up to **8x** faster in query speed.